# How to dynamically change Intersection Observer's configuration

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have a section on my page to which when user scrolls, an event fires. The solution uses `IntersectionObserver` which is perfect for my need. However, I would like to adapt the size of `rootMargin` of this observer, when the uses is already there.

Now the simplest approach when having an observer like this:

```
const options = { rootMargin: '20px' };
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

would be to assign the properties of it:

```
observer.rootMargin = '0px';
```

But is doesn't seem to work.

Is is possible and how to change the behaviour of once created Intersection Observer?

Comment: short: no, create a new observer.

Comment: May this is a bug: https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/issues/157

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot, the properties are readonly.

```
interface IntersectionObserver {
  readonly attribute Element? root;
  readonly attribute DOMString rootMargin;
  readonly attribute FrozenArray<double> thresholds;
  ...
```

You should just replace your old observer with a new one. Maybe copy over the old options and just set what you need.